# How can I support XML with or without namespace, with my WCF HTTP REST service

Tags: xml, wcf, serialization

I have a series of objects that look like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
  [DataContract(Namespace="")]
  public class MyClass1
  {
    [DataMember]
    public string MyProperty {get;set;}
  }
}
```

I have a method which exposes the WebInvoke that looks like this (very simplified as this actually does nothing right now, but still works for this test)

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "", Method="POST")]
public MyNamespace.MyClass1 GetItem(MyClass1 postedItem) { return postedItem; }
```

I would really like to be able to accept XML that looks like this:

```
<MyClass1>
  <MyProperty>1</MyProperty>
</MyClass1>
```

or this:

```
<MyClass1 xmlns:"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyNamespace">
  <MyProperty>1</MyProperty>
</MyClass1>
```

But so far my research seems to indicate this is not possible.  My only idea right now is to use a IDispatchMessageInspector and consume the message, remove the xmlns namespace, and then allow WCF to continue processing the message.  I have not had a lot of luck with this however, because once I consume the message it is no longer available for WCF to consume and deserialize.

Is there an easier way?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dispatcher, but once you consume the message, you'll need to recreate it before returning from the method. The code below shows an example of it.

```
public class StackOverflow_7506072
{
    [DataContract(Name = "MyClass1", Namespace = "")]
    public class MyClass1
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public class Service
    {
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "", Method = "POST")]
        public MyClass1 GetItem(MyClass1 postedItem) { return postedItem; }
    }
    public class MyInspector : IEndpointBehavior, IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(this);
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }

        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(ms);
            request.WriteMessage(w);
            w.Flush();
            ms.Position = 0;
            XElement element = XElement.Load(ms);
            if (element.Name.NamespaceName == "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyNamespace")
            {
                element.Name = XName.Get(element.Name.LocalName, "");
                foreach (XElement child in element.Descendants())
                {
                    if (child.Name.NamespaceName == "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyNamespace")
                    {
                        child.Name = XName.Get(child.Name.LocalName, "");
                    }
                }

                element.Attribute("xmlns").Remove();
            }

            XmlReader r = element.CreateReader();
            Message newRequest = Message.CreateMessage(r, int.MaxValue, request.Version);
            newRequest.Properties.CopyProperties(request.Properties);
            request = newRequest;
            return null;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        ServiceEndpoint endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Service), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MyInspector());
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        c.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "text/xml";
        string xml = "<MyClass1><MyProperty>123</MyProperty></MyClass1>";
        Console.WriteLine(c.UploadString(baseAddress + "/", xml));

        c = new WebClient();
        c.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "text/xml";
        xml = "<MyClass1 xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyNamespace\"><MyProperty>123</MyProperty></MyClass1>";
        Console.WriteLine(c.UploadString(baseAddress + "/", xml));

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I needed.  I will implement your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is a horrible idea. You're treating XML as though the standard doesn't matter.

The element `MyClass1` in the  `"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyNamespace"` namespace is not the same as the element `MyClass` in the default namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use WcfRestContrib to inject a custom XmlSerializer which supports this behavior. An example which uses an XmlSerializer that always omits namespaces entirely is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9267267/1512). You'll need to work out how to update the XmlSerializer to optionally support namespaces for deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

If you set Namespace for service to Empty, you do not need to pass xmlns. But you need root xml tag matching to method name i.e.

```
<GetItem>
<MyClass1>
  <MyProperty>1</MyProperty>
</MyClass1>
</GetItem>
```