# WCF serialization & namespace

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IEventDismiss
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [return:MessageParameter(Name="response")]
        [XmlSerializerFormat]
        Response EventDismissRequest(Request request);
    }

[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
[Serializable]
public sealed class Request
{
    [DataMember]
    public string EventID { get; set; }
}
```

Above is my definition of the WCF service I'm trying to run, with the above I would get the following request structure in my SOAPUI

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <tem:EventDismissRequest>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <tem:request>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <tem:EventID>?</tem:EventID>
     </tem:request>
  </tem:EventDismissRequest>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is there a way I can get rid of the namespace `tem` under request and `EventID` but leave it on `EventDismissRequest`? so that my reqeuest data structure would look something like below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <tem:EventDismissRequest>
     <request>
        <EventID>?</EventID>
     </request>
  </tem:EventDismissRequest>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: You should be able to accomplish what you want in a manner similar to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7507206/77074 Can I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: Thanks Oren, I'll look at that.  One of the client we have requested this...I know, I would not do this to myself.

Comment: I found this blog article called *Changing prefixes in XML responses for WCF services*, maybe it will help you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2010/06/13/changing-prefixes-in-xml-responses.aspx