# Remove xml namespaces from WCF restful response on containing and base objects

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-3.5, datacontractserializer

.NET 3.5

So I have come to asking this after some frustration.  The primary issue that I have is that SOME of my properties in a class that is being serialized ARE including the xmlns attibute in the XML.

The particular properties are on the base class of the object or on objects that are inside the object.  I have full control over these and have added the datacontract(NameSpace="") attribute to all of my data contracts.

I am not worried about the top level xmlns or the xmlns:i, but only the lower level ones in the classes.

See [Remove xml namespaces from WCF restful response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482856/remove-xml-namespaces-from-wcf-restful-response)

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
BaseClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name{get;set;}
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
OtherClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public decimal Income{get;set;}
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
DerivedClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Age{get;set;}

    [DataMember]
    public OtherClass Foo{get;set;}
}
```

On serialization of the Derived class, this is what I get in my XML.

```
<DerivedClass
    xmlns="http://IDontCareAboutThisOne"
    xmlns:i="http://IDontCareAboutThisOneEither">
    <Name xmlns="">iMortalitySX</Name>
    <Age>30</Age>
    <Foo>
        <Income xmlns="">0.0</Income>
    </Foo>
</DerivedClass>
```

This is of course just an example.  Additionally, if you are curious I have done this through WCF services and using the DataContractSerializer directly with the same results (as it should be).  I need this because of the amount of data being returned on an older network.  Every little bit I shave makes a huge difference.

Yes, I have considered JSON, but customer requirements have driven XML.  There are other reasons that I don't agree with either, but it needs to be in XML.  Also, just FYI a third party serializer is not an option on this one.  I am stuck with MS base stuff.  I am exposing this as a WebHttpBinding with the WebBehavior, as a REST type service.  I am NOT using the REST starter kit, nor will I.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [ContractNamespaceAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.contractnamespaceattribute.aspx) to move all your contract members to the same XML namespace.  That will get rid of the xmlns attributes on individual members.

Answer (score 1):

Watch out if you're using something like Fiddler to inspect your message because its XML view will ADD in namespaces trying to make it easier for you. However those namespaces aren't necessarily present in the original raw view.

I made the mistake of trying to research this problem when I didn't need to.

#### Xml view

Fiddler has added the namespace here under notes.

[image]

#### Raw view

The same node the namespace isn't present

[image]

Now I'm not saying there are never any namespaces in the raw message that I don't really need - just that the situation may not be as bad as you fear if you're using Fiddler to inspect the message.