# How to remove the name space from the XML tags

Tags: xslt

Could you please tell me how could I remove only the name space `xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"` from the XML tags?

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
<soapenv:Body>
<urn:BAPI_QM_DEFECT_RECORDING>
<AMOUNT xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">1</AMOUNT>
<DEFECT_CODE xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">393</DEFECT_CODE>
<DEFECT_DESC xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">393</DEFECT_DESC>
<DEFECT_PID xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">601000</DEFECT_PID>
<INSPID xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>
<ORDER xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">20262950</ORDER>
<ORIGIN_PID xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">600000</ORIGIN_PID>
<OVER_CONSUMP xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">text</OVER_CONSUMP>
</urn:BAPI_QM_DEFECT_RECORDING></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Tis has been asked a lot of time already - see [Remove xml namespaces from WCF restful response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482856/remove-xml-namespaces-from-wcf-restful-response) or many more for the platform of your choice. Also you maybe even don't need to remove them - what are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code by creating element use local-name which will take name without namespaces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="urn:BAPI_QM_DEFECT_RECORDING/*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```